# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, jestjs

I'm setting up nodejs so as to test my javascript codes using jest javascript test framework. What have I done wrongly?

#### `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "institute-jest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.0",
    "jest": "^23.4.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.12.0"
  }
}
```

I got this following error message after running `npm test` in the terminal

```
(node:5088) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Olakunle-PC\Desktop\nodejs\HomeStudyLabs\node_modules\jest\node_modules\chalk\index.js:72:75)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at _load_chalk (C:\Users\Olakunle-PC\Desktop\nodejs\HomeStudyLabs\node_modules\jest\node_modules\jest-cli\build\cli\index.js:67:43)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Olakunle-PC\Desktop\nodejs\HomeStudyLabs\node_modules\jest\node_modules\jest-cli\build\cli\index.js:29:32)
(node:5088) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5088) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate
the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: can you show your index.js file. I think the issue is in that file

Answer (score 1):

I did the following below to resolve the issue

- deleted `node_modules` directory.
- deleted `package-lock.json` file.
- run `npm clear cache --force`.
- and run `npm install`.

Answer (score -1):

If you get undefined error, you need to make sure that which ever variables throws undefined error, is assigned a value to it.

More detail check link [detail](https://codeburst.io/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-in-javascript-c81e00f4a5e3)
The following code maybe helpful for debug:

```
function test(t) {     
  if (t === undefined) { 
        console.log(t.tt)
  }
  return t;    
}
```

Comment: question asker is not asking about how to manage undefined or nulls. His question is about jest framework is not starting up via npm test.